# sed: replace nth character from bash variable

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm working on a "github-like" path utility to change directories, however my sed isn't working to replace the slash inside the only arg.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  echo "cd /path/to/folder/$1" | sed 's,/,/theme/,5'
fi
```

Running this utility

```
customcmd site/project
```

should return

```
cd /path/to/folder/site/theme/project
```

Comment: It works for me. What does it return to you?

Comment: have you tried `sed 's,\/,\/Skins\/,4'`?

Comment: command: site/project: No such file or directory

Comment: What is/is-expected-to-be `command`?

Comment: @Fede didn't work =/

Comment: @Rubens I forgot `command` is a utility, so I changed it to `customcmd`

Answer (score 1):

No need to fork a sub-shell and use `sed`. You are using `bash` so use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  echo "cd /path/to/folder/${1/\//\/theme/}"
fi
```

Make sure you give the script executable permission before running it like `customcmd ...`.